# How can i update app.config connectionstring Datasource value in C#?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, app-config, configuration-files

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString",String.Format("DataSource={0};")].ConnectionString=textBox1.Text;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

I'm having trouble at line two. I cant seem to get the syntax correct. As you can see, i only want to update the DataSource value only. For example, if current value is **Data Source=PC001\SQL2008EXPRESS**, i want it to be updated to what the client enters in textBox1.

EDIT: Example ConnectionString

```
<add name="ERPDatabaseTables" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ERPTables.csdl|res://*/ERPTables.ssdl|res://*/ERPTables.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=PC001\SQL2008EXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

so want to update **Data Source=PC001\SQL2008EXPRESS** portion only

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you actually want is:

```
Configuration config = 
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// Because it's an EF connection string it's not a normal connection string
// so we pull it into the EntityConnectionStringBuilder instead
EntityConnectionStringBuilder efb = 
    new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ERPDatabaseTables"]
            .ConnectionString);

// Then we extract the actual underlying provider connection string
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqb = 
    new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(efb.ProviderConnectionString);

// Now we can set the datasource
sqb.DataSource = textBox1.Text;

// Pop it back into the EntityConnectionStringBuilder 
efb.ProviderConnectionString = sqb.ConnectionString;

// And update...
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ERPDatabaseTables"]
    .ConnectionString = efb.ConnectionString;

config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

This presumes:

1. Your EF connection string exists in the app's config file
2. You have a reference to `System.Data.Entity`

Comment: yes, this is what i want but the changes are not being saved and no exception is thrown. Even after refreshing, the application is still retrieving data using the old dataSource. This is a windows forms application that am installing on client PCs

Comment: @sql.net - sorry missed the line of code to save the config, updated

Comment: looks like i'm getting there, but getting exception message "Keyword not supported: 'datasource'"

Comment: I should also mention that its an Entity Framework connection string

Comment: @ Kev Ω - Keyword not supported: 'datasource' error still comes up

Comment: @sql.net - what line does the exception get thrown on? Did you replace all of your code with mine? Also your user should not enter `Data Source=PC001\SQL2008EXPRESS` only the value is required, for example: `PC001\SQL2008EXPRESS`.

Comment: But does it write permanently to the app.config file? I tried it and it wasn't permanent, i don't want this to happen every time i start my application..

Comment: @BlankEDjok - I don't have time to check this right now, but I seem to remember it did permanently save these settings.

Comment: Even during debugging mode?